# How to draw a labelled color diagram

Tags: diagrams, tikz-graphs

I am new to the latex diagram and I can't find any model to draw the labeled color diagram below. I wonder if it's possible to draw it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tikz is very simple because in this case you only have to draw straight lines. With the following code you can draw your diagram.

```
\documentclass [tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \draw[thick,orange] (0,3) -- (6,3);
  \draw[thick,red]    (0,0) -- (2,0);
  \draw[thick,red]    (4,0) -- (6,0);
  \draw[thick,blue]   (2,0) -- (4,0);
  \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,6) -- (6,6) --(6,0);
  \draw[->] (3,6) --++(45:1) node [above right] {a};
  \draw[->] (1,-0.2) --++(270:1) node [below] {b};
  \draw[->] (3,-0.2) --++(270:1) node [below] {c};
  \draw[->] (5,-0.2) --++(270:1) node [below] {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You'll get something like this:
[image]